Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Conv2D: {'batch_input_shape': [None, 135, 135, 3]}
I have some models that were trained with an older version of Tensorflow, Keras and Python. Now I updated to Tensorflow 2.16.1, Keras 3.1.1 and Python 3.12.2. Now I cannot even load these models that I get a huge error message. The last message is:
Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Conv2D: {'batch_input_shape': [None, 135, 135, 3]}
Is there a way to access this model without downgrading or retraining the model?
I tried:
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
    models_folder = '/savedModels/models_stack/'
    model1 = load_model(f'{models_folder}model_best1.keras')


These area some of the error messages I got:
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Conv2D: {'batch_input_shape': [None, 135, 135, 3]}
Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Conv2D: {'batch_input_shape': [None, 135, 135, 3]}
TypeError: <class 'keras.src.layers.convolutional.conv2d.Conv2D'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by get_config() are explicitly deserialized in the model's from_config() method.
and more...

Do you really need to update to tf 2.16? Indeed it uses Keras 3 and it's a breaking change. You can still install and use the old Keras with TF 2.16 if that helps.

I found it much easier to use the .h5 format:
model.save(path/to/model.h5)
tf.keras.models.load_model(path/to/model.h5) works with no issues.
I don't know if you have the model in memory somewhere, but if you do, save it to .h5 instead of .keras

Alternatively, try Python 3.12.1 and tensorflow 2.18.0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
